# Whats the built in function that Finds next largest prime number in java?

Tags: java, primes

Does the Java API provide a function which computes the next largest prime number given an input x?

Comment: Not until you write one.

Comment: I think for someone at Sun / Oracle to develop this; test it; QA it; code review it; document it; and translate the documentation; for something that will be RARELY used; would be a waste of money.

Comment: What does your iphone have to do with this question?

Comment: Dang! Alright cool thank you!

Comment: Its in the Math package.  Math.completeHomeWorkAssignment(CS101Assignment assignment);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be a pretty esoteric method, and not really a great candidate for inclusion in a general class library. You would need to write this yourself, using either a [test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) or a [sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin).

Comment: sieve is used for finding all primes _less_ than a particular number - in this case use a test :)

Comment: Sure, but you can always generate primes up to N *first*, and then "next" (below N) becomes trivial. :)

Comment: why would it be esoteric? why it's not a "great" candidate for a library? and why there is a method in the JDK that does exactly this? BigInteger.nextProbablePrime(). i think you didn't give the right answer and i am shure you didn't give the solution.

Answer (score 5):

There is `BigInteger.nextProbablePrime()` which may suit if you are working with large integers.  Otherwise you can write your own easily enough.  Here is one I prepared earlier:

```
static long nextPrime(long previous) {
  if (previous < 2L) { return 2L; }
  if (previous == 2L) { return 3L; }
  long next = 0L;
  int increment = 0;
  switch ((int)(previous % 6L)) {
    case 0: next = previous + 1L; increment = 4; break;
    case 1: next = previous + 4L; increment = 2; break;
    case 2: next = previous + 3L; increment = 2; break;
    case 3: next = previous + 2L; increment = 2; break;
    case 4: next = previous + 1L; increment = 2; break;
    case 5: next = previous + 2L; increment = 4; break;
  }
  while (!isPrime(next)) {
    next += increment;
    increment = 6 - increment;   // 2, 4 alternating
  }
  return next;
}
```

This uses a 2, 4 wheel to skip over multiples of 2 and 3.  You will need a prime testing method:

```
boolean isPrime(long toTest) { ... }
```

which returns `true` if its parameter is prime, `false` otherwise.

Comment: isn't THAT the solution? everybody in this post says that there is NO method to get a prime numbers - but there is. BigInteger.nextProbablePrime() like rossum says. the people are making fun of the question, saying that you should make your homework on your own, but they don't even know the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there really is no such function!

Answer (score 1):

Java **java.math.BigInteger class contains a method nextProbablePrime ()** to check the primality of a number.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class NextPrime {

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                        int number = 83;
                        Long nextPrime = nextPrime(number);
                        System.out.println(nextPrime + " next prime to " + number);

            }

            /**
             * method to find next prime
             * @param number
             * @return boolean
             */
            private static Long nextPrime(int number) {
                        BigInteger bValue = BigInteger.valueOf(number);

                        /**
                         * nextProbablePrime method used to generate next prime.
                         * */
                        bValue = bValue.nextProbablePrime();

                        return Long.parseLong(bValue.toString());
            }
}
```

**Output:**
            89 next prime to 83

For more information, see my blog:
http://javaexplorer03.blogspot.in/2016/05/generate-next-prime-of-number-in-java.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public class nextprime {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int count = 0;
    int n = 17;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            count++;

        }
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        System.out.println("prime");
        for (int p = n + 1; p >0; p++) {
            int y=0;
            for (int i = 2; i <= p / 2; i++) {
                if (p % i == 0) {
                    y++;

                }
            }
            if(y==0)
            {
                System.out.println("Next prime "+p);
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.print("not prime");
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: As far as I can read this, this will first determine that 17 is indeed prime, than inefficiently determine that 18 isn't and then determine that 19 is.

Answer (score 0):

`Primes.nextPrime(int n)` from [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) is what you need.